# C++ - Problems implementing Quicksort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, recursion, quicksort

so I'm new at recursion and I've trying to implement some algorithms, such like quicksort down below, but It doesn't seem to be working that well... I think the problem is in partition, but I'm not sure what the problem could be...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int MAX = 100;

typedef int matrix[MAX];

struct Taula{
    matrix m;
    int n;
};
void wwap(Taula &t, int n, int i, int posPivot)
{
    int aux = t.m[posPivot];
    t.m[posPivot] = t.m[i];
    t.m[i] = aux;
}
void partition(Taula &t, int n, int left, int right, int &posPivot)
{
    int pivot = t.m[right];
    posPivot = left;
    for (int i = left; i < right-1; i++){
        if (t.m[i] < pivot){
            swap(t,n,i,posPivot);
            posPivot = posPivot+1;
        }
    }
    swap(t,n,posPivot,right);
}
void quicksort(Taula &t, int n, int left, int right)
{
    int k;
    if (left < right){
        particio(t,t.n,left,right,k);
        quicksort(t,t.n,left,k-1);
        quicksort(t,t.n,k+1,right);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Taula t;
    t.n = 0;

    cout << "INTEGER SEQUENCE ENDED WITH -2:" << endl;
    int x; cin >> x;

    while (x != -2){
        t.m[t.n] = x;
        t.n++;
        cin >> x;
    }
    cout << t.n << " ELEMENTS" << endl;
    quicksort(t,t.n,0,t.n);
    cout << "SORT:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < t.n; i++) cout << t.m[i] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This would be an output example:

```
INTEGER SEQUENCE ENDED WITH -2:
45
-4
-9
-3
13
64
789
-645
78
-62
12
35
-14
6
0
21
-5
454
-2
18 ELEMENTS
SORT:
-645
-14
-9
-62
-5
-3
-4
0
12
6
13
35
45
64
78
789
21
4254617

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 31.583 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: particio?? do you mean partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Lomuto partition approach. Right way to do it:

```
  for (int i = left; i <= right-1; i++){
        if (t.m[i] <= pivot){
            swap(t,n,i,posPivot);
            posPivot = posPivot+1;
        }
```

The second issue - main call should be:

```
 quicksort(t,t.n,0,t.n - 1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much... I thought that the t-n-1 wasn't needed in the main due to I was doing the for loop until i < right-1.

Comment: But you use m[right] as pivot, that is iilegal for right = n

Answer (score 0):

you have to go from left until you find some bigger number than your pivot and than from right to left until you find a lower number... (this two loops make the quicksort extremely fast...) look at this code...

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Quicksort

you need this both lines:

```
while Array[L2] < PivotValue do // scan left partition
    L2 := L2 + 1;
while Array[R2] > PivotValue do // scan right partition
    R2 := R2 - 1;
```

so here is your problem:

```
for (int i = left; i < right-1; i++){
    if (t.m[i] < pivot){
        swap(t,n,i,posPivot);
        posPivot = posPivot+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: and you have to stop when L2 is > R2 not when left > right -1

Comment: Thomas, thank you for you answer, I've already fixed it with @MBo help... Even though you helped me understanding the algorithm, thanks!